# Javascript - Is it possible to convert a varying-length if-else statement into for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I have the following code which includes a varying number (nk) of if-else conditions.

```
var n = 128; // n is 128 or greater.
var nk = 4; // nk is varying, can be 4,6,8,12,16 etc. smaller than n.

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if ((i < 1 * n / nk) { ... }
    else if (i < 2 * n / nk) { ... }
    else if (i < 3 * n / nk) { ... }
    else if (i < 4 * n / nk) { ... }
}
```

Is it possible to turn the if-else statements into a for loop (or anything else) so that it can work with varying nk? Right now, to account for varying nk values, I have to write multiple for loops with if-else statements.

I tried the following, which obviously does not work:

```
for (let i = 1; i < nk; i++) {
    if (x < i * n / nk)) { /* code here is a function of i */ }
}
```

Comment: You still have different code executed for each condition. Converting to a loop would at best simplify your conditions into one line but you still have to execute different code for each different condition, thus the total lines of code is hardly going to be impacted. You still have `nk` numeber of branches and if you collapse your conditions into one line, you now need to expand your results to try and figure out which corresponding code to use. You can encode this into a table with condition + result but that just move branching elsewhere.

Comment: The code to be executed is the same, which is a function of i, would that change your opinion?

Comment: This is (for me) a bit difficult to see what you are trying to achieve without the missing bits (the action to be performed on each condition, lower/upper limits of `nk`, where `x` and `n` come from... You might get a better idea if you try to write in plain English (or explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)) what you are trying to do. My hunch is that if all the actions are similar, there would actually be some formula to replace this (parameterized function). Else, you won't be able to simplify (as @VLAZ says).

Comment: @yenren then you don't have `if`/`else` chain which signifies *mutually exclusive* rules. What you have is a weirdly typed OR condition, since if *any* is true, you want to execute the same code.

Comment: @VLAZ I expressed myself wrongly, code is not the same, but is the same function of i only.

Comment: @VLAZ I had a typo in my code, made a final edit. What I do inside the if condition is canvas rotation. x is always <= n. n is 128 or more. nk can be 4,6,810,12 etc. The whole code is much complicated so I simplified to give an idea what I am trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: If you really-really wanted to, you can make it an ugly, fragile `switch`: `switch(Math.floor(x/(n*nk)))`. Then `case 0:` would be the first block (`if ((x < 1 * n / nk)`), and so on.

Comment: @tevemadar, but how many cases will I need to have? nk is variable, that's why I'm trying to get rid of the if-else statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further trial and error, I reached the following solution, which works as I needed. The key point was to use closed interval check inside `if`; and use of `break` for better performance:

```
n = 128;
var nk = 4;

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    let nkk = n / nk;

    for (let k = 0; k < nk; k++) {
        if (i > k * nkk && i <= (k + 1) * nkk) {
            // ...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies for not properly expressing my question, this question may either be closed or kept if the answer might be useful to anyone else in the future.

Comment: Your inner loop is redundant, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You need neither an inner loop or conditionals. You can calculate the value of k using the `Math.floor` function as follows:

```
const n = 128;
const nk = 4;

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    const k = Math.floor((i-1)/(n/nk));
    // do something with k and i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to convert the varying-length if-else statement into a for loop. However, you need to modify the loop condition and the if condition to accommodate the varying nk value

```html
var x, n; // defined before
var nk = 4;

for (let i = 0; i < nk; i++) {
    if (i === nk - 1 || x < (i + 1) * n / nk) {
        // Code here is a function of i
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work in my case.

Comment: Where from did you get the `i === nk - 1 ||`?

Comment: @Bergi [earlier version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76286671/revisions) where the *last* case was was `x < 4 * n` rather than the progressive `x < someInteger * n / nk` conditions before that